# Calling a function inside another on Class JS

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having trouble calling a specific function inside another on class. Example:

```
var class = {
    function1 : {
        function2 : {
            class.function1.function3();
        },
        function3 : {
            // my code
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to simplify calling this function within function1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring class, function1, 2 and 3 as objects, rather than functions. You need to do:

```
var class = {
    function1 : {
        function2 : function() {
            class.function1.function3();
        },
        function3 : function() {
            // my code
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to make `function2` and `function3` into actual functions. That said, you'll probably want to look into how OOP is done in JavaScript (which is what I'm guessing you're tryring to do), I'm sure google will give you some good hints. I'm no expert myself, but I guess you usually do it something like this:

```
function class() {
  this.function2 = function() {
  };
  // etc.
}
var o = new class();
```

Comment: OK. Following his example, as if I'd had a second function (function3) inside class and tried to call it within the function2?

Comment: Wow, I totally missed this comment. So now, 2.5 years later, I guess you've already figured it out, but in case anyone else comes along: It all comes down to the calling convention. If you have an object `o`, and you call a function `f1` which is a member, using `o.f1()`, the js engine will automatically assign `this` to be `o`. So if you in `f1` want to call `f2`, you can do `this.f2()`, again, `this` for `f2` will be set to current value of `this` in `f1` which is `o`. NOTE: In contrast, if you do `var x = o.f1; x()`, `this` will not be set (or remain unchanged if already set).

Comment: Perfect! Currently I know how to do, and what you just said makes complete sense and knowledge is always welcome, thanks =D